# x-appengine-citylatlong is not giving correct Lat & Lag

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, geolocation

I've hosted my website in Firebase. I'm using firebase onRequest functions to track user Lat & Lag.

Below is the code,

```
 User Geo Location Coordinates (Lat,Lag): ${req.headers['x-appengine-citylatlong']}
```

I accessed the website from my location, but firebase function gives me different Lat/Lag.

I'm getting correct Lat/Lag from this website https://www.gps-coordinates.net/

Currently I'm getting this Lat/Lag listed in this website  https://ipinfo.io/

How do I get exact user coordinates ? please help.

Note: I can't use client side to get Lat/Lag. I have to do this in server side

Answer (score 0):

Google App Engine-specific headers may not be enough for your expectations. You cannot get exact location using headers only. According to [**App Engine-specific headers**](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/reference/request-response-headers#app_engine-specific_headers):

> **X-Appengine-CityLatLong**
>
> Latitude and longitude of the **city** from which the request originated. This string might look like "37.386051,-122.083851" for a request from Mountain View.

Getting a precise address from the server without data and consent from the client side is impossible. That would be a huge privacy issue. I'm not sure if you're using web or mobile, but [location permissions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/location#location_permissions) will always apply regardless of the platform.

This is also mentioned from this [thread](http://html5doctor.com/finding-your-position-with-geolocation/):

> The specification explicitly states that since the nature of the API (Geolocation) also exposes the user’s location and therefore could compromise their privacy, the user’s permission to attempt to obtain the geolocation information must be sought before proceeding

While Maps SDK has [wrapper libraries](https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/client-library#why-use-the-client-libraries) so you can run them on a server, Geolocation API is not mentioned, so what you want is really not possible.